# Amalgamation of submodules: How can I make this second module visible to the python interpreters?

Tags: python

This is the directory layout

```
❯ tree
.
├── src1
│   └── some
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.pyc
│       └── fish
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── __init__.pyc
└── src2
    └── some
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __init__.pyc
        └── bird
            ├── __init__.py
            └── __init__.pyc
```

I want to be able to import both `some.fish` and `some.bird` module.

If I set the env variable `PYTHONPATH` this way:

```
❯ export PYTHONPATH=./src1:./src2
❯ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 30 2014, 18:28:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import some.fish
>>> import some.bird
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bird
>>>
```

It is possible at all to make the `bird` module appear under `some`?

The solutions I want to avoid:

1) Change the directory structure

2) Change the name of the parent package `some`

In the other word, can I amalgamate two submodules under the same module name without putting the files under the same directory structure?

Comment: Is there a reason that the package in both src1 and src2 have the same name `some`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a conflicting name `some` for two modules, the one in `src1` and the one in `src2`. In order to fix this, you have many options:

- Rename `some` folders to `some1`, `some2`.
- Move `bird`, `fish` to the same folder
- Add the parents of `src1` and `src2` instead and import modules like:

  ```
  >>> import src1.some.fish
  >>> import src2.some.bird
  ```

Comment: These are the options I want to avoid. I will update the question

Comment: `src1` and `src2` are not supposed to be module names.

Comment: You want to have 2 modules with same name but different content and importing them same time? impossible. module name should be unique.